# Do the canonical commutation relations have any connection to geometry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, geometry, commutator, non-commutative-geometry

I was wondering if the [canonical commutation relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) have any connection to geometry?
If so, could you explain the connection in fairly simple and intuitive terms?

Comment: This is an interesting subject,  it would  be very difficult for me to properly answer here, however, I think You can take a look at the paper "from equations of motions to canonical commutation relations". It contains a lot of discussion on the theme, as well as a very good bibliography on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a fairly broad topic.

1. Here is one way [CCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)s arise from a rather large class of geometries: Given a [Fedosov manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedosov_manifold) $(M,\omega, \nabla)$ [i.e. a manifold $M$ endowed with a symplectic $2$-form $\omega$ with a compatible torsion-free connection$^1$ $\nabla$], Fedosov proved the existence of an associative star product $$f\star g~=~fg +{\cal O}(\hbar)\tag{1}$$ of functions $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$ in the context of [deformation quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization)$^2$. The star commutator $$[f\stackrel{\star}{,}g]~:=~f\star g-g\star f~=~i\hbar\{f,g\}_{PB}+{\cal O}(\hbar^2) \tag{2}$$ 
   corresponds to a commutator of operators via a symbol-operator correspondence map. The [Darboux theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem) ensures the local existence of canonical coordinates $(q^1, \ldots, q^n,p_1, \ldots, p_n)$. CCRs therefore make sense.
2. For an elementary discussion of the connection between commutators & Poisson brackets, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ A symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ always has such connection $\nabla$; it is however not unique. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296519/2451) related Phys.SE post.

$^2$ Kontsevich extended the [construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontsevich_quantization_formula) of an associative star product (1) to an arbitrary [Poisson manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold).

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the gauge potential is identical to connection where the gauge potential is related to amplitude (field variable).

The commutation relation in quantum theory can be written as the commutation relation of field variables (amplitude).

So it is natural to have the commutation relation expressed in connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).