# Liouville one-form local Vs global meaning

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism

Let's take the so-called *Liouville one-form* $\theta = \sum_i p_i dq^i$ (AKA *Canonical one-form*, *Tautological one-form*, *Symplectic potential*, etc.), defined on cotangent bundles.

Some contributions (e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88925/p-dq-is-the-tautological-one-form) discussion) cite a difference between its "local" and "global" meaning: what's the difference between the two, and what is meant by "local" and "global"?

Comment: Theres a difference between its local and global description - is this what you mean? For example, the description that you have of the Liouville 1-form in your question is local as it uses coordinates and coordinates are a local description.

Comment: So @MoziburUllah the "global" description means "coordinates-free"?

Comment: Usually, yes; I was questioning what you meant by 'meaning'?

Comment: About "meaning", I just used the term from here: [link](https://books.google.nl/books?id=uycWAu1yY2gC&lpg=PA128&dq=canonical%20one%20form%20hamiltonian&pg=PA128#v=onepage&q=%22local%20meaning%22&f=false).

Comment: "Local" is description in a local chart. "Global" is a description as a differential 1-form on the whole manifold. In your case, $\theta$ is a differential 1-form on a cotangent bundle $T^*Q$. By denoting $\pi:T^*Q\to Q$ the bundle projection, a global description (or definition) of $\theta$ would be $\theta|_p(v) := p(\pi_*(v))$ for $p\in T^*Q$, $v\in T_p T^*Q$. A "global" meaning of this 1-form, the tautological aspect, is that for $\alpha\in \Omega^1(Q)$ we have $\alpha^*\theta = \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you @NAC . Just a question: with $\alpha ^* \theta$ you mean the pullback of $\theta$ by $\alpha$?

Comment: @LoScrondo Yes.